# Display Offers in Seperate page

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, offers

I'm using magento 1.9.

I have added some `Shopping CART price rules` and `Catalog price rules`.
Is it possible to display these products (offer products) in separate page/home page?

Are there any free extensions available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your rules, and how they are setup. I gather you are using some condition like 'where sku is one of' ?

The easiet way forwatd is to place all these products in a category. You can the display the category as you would any other. That includes on homepage via cms directives in content area.

How to get these  'on sale' products into the category.

You can manually maintain the category products, or you can use an extension to automate that.

Since you specifically ask for a free module I will not mention my really feature rich dynamic category products extension that can do this and more...but direct you to a free 'not so feature rich' alternative.

https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory/blob/develop/README.md

I am not sure if the free extension can do rules related to catalog sales rules. It may suit your needs.

I hope that helps.